# Paste into SSH terminal capitalizes last character and doesn't allow me to edit it

Tags: ssh, terminal, copy-paste, paste

I'm running Terminal on my Mac and ssh'ing into a Linux host.  I've had 2 issues around copying and pasting text into my Terminal:

1. When I'm just running local Terminal commands on my Mac (not though ssh), I sometimes get weird characters around text that I paste, like `00~pastedtext01~`.  I googled around and found out that this was apparently due to "bracketed paste".  I was able to fix this problem by running the command `printf '\e[?2004l'` whenever it happens.
2. When I ssh into my Linux host, when I paste text it will often capitalize the last character of whatever I'm pasting, and the cursor will turn gray and I won't be able to type additional characters or delete characters from whatever I pasted.  My only two options at that point are to either ^C to break onto the next line without running the command, or hit enter and run the messed up command.  It doesn't happen 100% of the time.  If I copy something and then repeatedly paste it into the shell, I'll see this issue occur about 90% of the time.  I have no idea why it's apparently non-deterministic like this.  I thought this might also be due to "bracketed paste" issues, but no matter how many times I run the commands `printf '\e[?2004l'` and `set enable-bracketed-paste off`, the issue persists.  It even persists when I exit and re-ssh to the host, so I know it's not due to running any program like vim, since the problem still happens even immediately after I've ssh'ed into the host.  Can someone please help???  This is killing my productivity!

Here's what a paste with this issue looks like:

[image: Paste with issue]

I'm aware that other questions have been asked along these lines, like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379653/paste-has-odd-behavior-in-shell) from Stack Exchange, but none of the answers on any of these posts have worked for me, so I think my problem may be slightly different than those...

Comment: Small Update: I've noticed that after I paste, I can press the `i` key and it will then allow me to edit the text I pasted. This is the same key you'd use to enter "insert" mode in vim, so now I'm thinking it might have something to do with vim, but I still don't understand how that'd be possible given that the issue happens even on a fresh terminal where I've never opened vim.

Comment: Which shell you are using?

Comment: It looks like I'm just using zsh

Answer (score 0):

Check your ZSH config

```
cat ~/.zshrc
```

Check if in `plugins=(...)` you find `safe-paste`. If it's there, edit the config and delete `safe-paste`.

```
if grep -q "safe-paste" "~/.zshrc"; then   # checks if str in contained in file
    sed -e s/safe-paste//g -i ~/.zshrc     # if so, it replaces the str with nothing
fi
```

As a one liner:

```
if grep -q "safe-paste" "~/.zshrc"; then; sed -e s/safe-paste//g -i ~/.zshrc; fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately there is no `plugins` or `safe-paste` anywhere in my `~/.zshrc` file.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if `safe-paste` mode is on?  Maybe it's being turned on somewhere else?

Comment: @Dasmowenator ok do you paste with ctrl+v or ctrl+shift+v? Just trying to narrow it down now

Comment: It's just Command+V, no Shift needed (I'm using a Mac, so I guess that'd be the equivalent of just Ctrl+V)